# PHP: connect drop-down list with submit button and if/else statement

Tags: php, if-statement, button, drop-down-menu, submit

So, to explain my question. I have four .php codes on web server, and I have drop down list in php code also (it includes name of all four php files that are on server). I have also submit button.

I should do following: User choose one name from drop down list, click submit button, and than that php file should be called and shown on web page.

The problem is, I don't know hot to connect these three part of php code.

```
<p>
  What Genre you want?
<select name="Ganre">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="FPS">FPS</option>
  <option value="JRPG">JRPG</option>
  <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
  <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

<if (Genre == "FPS") { ?>
<form method="get" action="FPS.php"}>
  <else if (Genre == "JRPG") { ?>
  <form method="get" action="JRPG.php"}>
    <else if (Genre == "RPG") { ?>
    <form method="get" action="RPG.php"}>
      <else if (Genre == "Sports") { ?>
      <form method="get" action="Sports.php"}>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the code you provided:

- You have no opening `<?php` for those closing `?>`.
- You have lots of invalid syntax, like `If (Genre == "FPS") {` (What is *Genre*?) or like 
  `<else if`
- You have two spellings of "Genre" (Ganre).

There are several ways to do what you want. As you did not mention Javascript, I propose a PHP-only solution. You would just let the form submit to the 
same PHP file, and there detect which choice was made. Then let PHP redirect to the 
page of choice:

```
<?php
   if (isset($_GET["genre"])) {
       // User submitted their choice, so redirect to that page
       // Make sure not to echo anything when using header():
       header("Location: " . $_GET["genre"] . ".php");
       // Make sure to not execute any other code in this file
       exit();
   } 
   // User did not yet submit a choice, so present list
?>
<form method="get">
    <p>
        What Genre you want?
        <select name="genre">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="FPS">FPS</option>
            <option value="JRPG">JRPG</option>
            <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
            <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add onchange into select tag and add below javasctipt code.

```
<form method="get" action="">
  <select name="Ganre" onchange="actionChangdde(this)">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="FPS">FPS</option>
    <option value="JRPG">JRPG</option>
    <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
    <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
  </select>                     
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    function actionChangdde(sel){
        var getSelVal = sel.value;
        var repAction = getSelVal+'.php';               
        sel.parentElement.setAttribute("action", repAction);                
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Nice solution! Maybe the name attribute of the **select** element should be removed to avoid its value gets appended to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<form>
<p>
  What Genre you want?
<select name="Ganre" id="genre">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="FPS">FPS</option>
  <option value="JRPG">JRPG</option>
  <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
  <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_button"/>
</p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var dropDownValue = $('#genre').val();
      $('#submit_button').click(function () {
      if($('#genre').val() == "FPS"){
        window.location="FPS.php";
      }
      if($('#genre').val() == "JRPG"){
        window.location="JRPG.php";
      }
      if($('#genre').val() == "RPG"){
        window.location="RPG.php";
      }
      if($('#genre').val() == "Sports"){
        window.location="Sports.php";
      }
      if($('#genre').val() == ""){
        return false;
      }

  });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There is no need to involve jQuery in this.

Comment: I tried code. When I choose for example RPG and click submit button, it just clear my selection in drop-down list - it didn't call/show RPG file on page.

Comment: I have not tested this code but just give you overview.You can try in that way.